# Intel SSD bug: unbootable after sleep mode with low battery. need to backup data

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup, ssd, data-recovery

After putting my notebook to sleep while it was on a low battery state I pluged my cable in and turned it on again. Then I got error messages about writing data to swap, ssd superblock and I/O errors on my intel ssd.

I've already found a way to erase the SSD and make it work again ([Image or reset broken SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409684/image-or-reset-broken-ssd)). But I need to find a way to backup or view my data. The data on my ssd is really important for me (bachelor thesis). Plz help me guys any ideas are welcome.

Here are some information I got using a livecd:

**fdisk -l**

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 8 MB, 8388608 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1 cylinders, total 16384 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

**hdparm -I /dev/sda**

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       INTEL SSDSA2BW120G3A                    
        Serial Number:      BAD_CTX     00000150
        Firmware Revision:  4PC10302
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6
Standards:
        Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
        Supported: 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 8
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:      16128
        LBA    user addressable sectors:      16384
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:      16384
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           8 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           8 MBytes 
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 1
        DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Phy event counters
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT LBA Segment Access (AC2)
           *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
           *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
           *    Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM
Security: 
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
                frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 500151795954bb60
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 001517
        Unique ID       : 95954bb60
Checksum: correct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably out of luck; that bug is horrid. However, give [gpart](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gpart) [image: Install gpart] a go. Good luck!

Comment: no luck with gpart and testdisk. I'll give up. Thanks for your support!